# Implementation of backpropagation algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm building a neural network with the architecture:

`input layer` --> `fully connected layer` --> `ReLU` --> `fully connected layer` --> `softmax`

I'm using the equations outlined here [DeepLearningBook](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html#problem_470307) to implement backprop. I think my mistake is in eq. 1. When differentiating do I consider each example independently yielding an N x C (no. of examples x no. of classes) matrix or together to yield an N x 1 matrix?

```
# derivative of softmax
da2 = -a2    # a2 comprises activation values of output layer
da2[np.arange(N),y] += 1
da2 *= (a2[np.arange(N),y])[:,None]

# derivative of ReLU
da1 = a1    # a1 comprises activation values of hidden layer
da1[a1>0] = 1

# eq. 1
mask = np.zeros(a2.shape)
mask = [np.arange(N),y] = 1
delta_2 = ((1/a2) * mask) * da2 / N 
# delta_L = - (1 / a2[np.arange(N),y])[:,None] * da2 / N

# eq.2
delta_1 = np.dot(delta_2,W2.T) * da1

# eq. 3
grad_b1 = np.sum(delta_1,axis=0)
grad_b2 = np.sum(delta_2,axis=0)

# eq. 4
grad_w1 = np.dot(X.T,delta_1)
grad_w2 = np.dot(a1.T,delta_2)
```

Oddly, the commented line in eq. 1 returns the correct value for biases but I can't seem to justify using that equation since it returns an N x 1 matrix which is multiplied with the corresponding rows of da2.

Edit: I'm working on the assignment problems of the CS231n course which can be found here: [CS231n](http://cs231n.github.io/assignments2016/assignment1/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  Specifically, please include the "required" code to illustrate the problem: your posted code should run as given, by itself.

Comment: Also, what is your purpose in doing this?  There are several good frameworks that supply the desired layers and connections for you, with backprop included.

Comment: It's primarily for learning.

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't find any explanation about this elsewhere. So I write a post :) Please read it [here](https://nimitpattanasri.github.io/2017/01/10/a-modular-approach-to-implementing-fully-connected-neural-networks.html).